# Using textbox values in IN statement

Tags: sql, ms-access, textbox

I'm trying to get this to work? How can I set a textbox to be used in an `IN()` statement? I would like users to be able to list out countries they'd like to query on

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE CountryID IN (forms!frmImport!txtCountries)
```

Comment: What technology? ASp.NET? Php? Html? Phone App?

Comment: Oops in Access using either SQL or VBA

Answer (score 1):

You can't just put the name of the textbox directly into the SQL string.
Instead, you need to use the content of the textbox to build a SQL string like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE CountryID IN (1,2,3)
```

If your users enter a comma-separated list of CountryIDs into the textbox, you can build the SQL like this:

```
Dim SQL As String

SQL = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE CountryID IN (" & Forms!frmImport!txtCountries & ")"
```

But I wouldn't do it this way because it's simple, but prone to input errors and SQL injection.

A better way would be to use a list box, set the `Multi Select` property *(so that multiple entries can be selected)* and fill it with a list of all available countries.

Then, the user can select the ones that he wants, and you can build the SQL string using the selected items from the listbox:

```
Dim ListItem As Variant
Dim CountryList As String
Dim SQL As String

For Each ListItem In Forms!frmImport!lstCountries.ItemsSelected
    If CountryList > "" Then
        CountryList = CountryList & ","
    End If
    CountryList = CountryList & ListItem
Next

SQL = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE CountryID IN (" & CountryList & ")"
```