# Search a textbox for a value in a query

Tags: ms-access

I've got a fully functional database built. 
But I have really no idea how to do query's in access 2010.

I would just like to know how to search a textbox for a value in a query.

For example:

I have a Field in a table named "Allergies" its stored as Text and the user may write a list of allergies in there, divided my commas.

What I want to do is build a query showing the names of the people with a certain allergy, say "Penicillin".

I would like a statement that I can put in the Criteria of the query builder for the Allergies variable.

I do not know the code to do this.

EDIT---------

I'm trying the following in the Criteria, but am not getting any results.

```
Like "*Penicillin*"
```

Also just tried this and didn't get any results.

```
In ("Penicillin")
```

Thanks!

Comment: I already answered this exact question here: [Using textbox values in IN statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127816/using-textbox-values-in-in-statement) ...but I can't flag this question as a duplicate of it, because my answer there has been neither upvoted nor accepted.

Comment: Ok thanks. But I want to do it in the query builder not sql or vba if possible.

Comment: If this `Like "*Penicillin*"` doesn't work (or the In() version) then either it is spelt differently in the field or the field doesn't contain this value. (Perhaps the field is linked to another table, so the text itself is in the other table's field.)

Comment: Oh. My. Gosh. I feel so stupid! It was spelled wrong in the table! Thank you so so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for their help.

I actually made a stupid spelling mistake!

This is the code that works for anyone who is interested:

```
Like "*Penicillin*"
```